# how to make a php/ajax script to show text depending on function of php script

Tags: php, ajax, loading-image

So I have a script I'm working on, within the script is a ajax call to another php file that pulls data from an api.  There is three different functions to the api script.  So when my ajax is called I have it showing a loading image but I also want it to display text depending on what function of the api script is running.

This is what I'm using now

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
function loadingAjax(div_id) {
      var divIdHtml = $("#"+div_id).html();
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "testmash.php?tag=<? echo $ptag; ?>",
           data: "tag=John&id=28",
           beforeSend: function() {
              $("#loading-image").show();
           },
           success: function(msg) {
              $("#"+div_id).html(divIdHtml + msg);
              $("#loading-image").hide();
           }
      });
}
</script> 
<body onLoad="loadingAjax('myDiv');">
    <div id="myDiv" style="margin-top:500" align="center">
        <img id="loading-image" src="ajax-loader.gif" style="display:none;"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

So when loading the testmash.php file I want to show my ajax-loader.gif plus a message that says "blah blah blah" for function 1 after function 1 is done and function 2 starts a new message appears saying"we are doing function 2" and so on for the amount of function I have or even like a check list when the ajax is called have a list with the three functions and as the complete have a green check mark or what not display next to it until its done.  I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Add a div to your 'myDiv' call it with an id 'message' and change it with javascript accordingly when calling the functions?

```
$('#ajaxMessage').html('My message');
```

Hopefully this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use nested callback function